# subscribing after inserting the data in Reactive Repositories

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I am a complete newbie into the reactive world, so while going through some of the examples on Reactive Repositories I found below:

```
reactiverepository.save(employee).subscribe() // subscribing to make the publisher emit the data

reactiverepository.findAll() // no subscribe() ?
```

I know in order for a publisher(Flux in the above case) to emit the data, we need to `subscribe()` to it. But why don't we have the same `subscribe()` calls in other CRUD methods like in the above example? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

reactor works with the concept `producer`and `consumer`. The `consumer` `subscribes` to the `producer` and `nothing will happen until you subscribe`.

When using `webflux`, which is basically `spring-web` but implemented with `reactor` the concept goes that `the final consumer is usually the one subscribing`.

You can think of it as the database is the `producer` and the calling `client` (webpage, react app, mobile app) is the `consumer`and when the client initiates a call to the backend, the client `subscribes`to your `server`and the `server`in turn `subscribes` to the `database`(remember? producer, the database produces data).

So your server is basically just forwarding the data to the calling client, which means that usually you just take the data and return it out to the client, and the framework will handle the "subscription", automatically.

Which usually means, you should NOT subscribe in your application, instead, you should chain on the calls, and always keep the chain intact so that your server can produce items to the client.

So when should you `subscribe` in your server?

Well one reason could be that you have a running job in your server that maybe fetches data from one server and inserts it into it's database. Then your service is the initiating client, subscribing to another server, the other server produces items to you, you receive them and insert them into your database.

but for instance in your example:

```
// first we fetch all, we filter, then we save, and we return back to the calling client keeping the chain intact, and no subscriptions
return reactiverepository.findAll()
    .filter(employes -> //some criteria)
    .flatMap(employee -> reactiverepository.save(employee));
```

Answer (score 0):

At the first, you should know about the hot and cold publishers. I'd suggest seeing this [article](https://www.vinsguru.com/reactor-hot-publisher-vs-cold-publisher/)

The code you write in the reactive programming world is a **description** of what you want to do (In the reactor world they called it assembly, I'd suggest seeing this [issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1418#issuecomment-436570880) to better understand the difference between Assembly and Execution) after the data is ready and **will not run exactly after your code is executed**.

The second thing to keep in mind is that you are always in a chain and you only need one subscription on this chain.

For example, suppose you want to get all the data from the repository and filter them with one field and then return it to the outside of the method. So you should do something like this:

```
return reactiveRepository.findAll().filter { //filter with one field } //or doing something different with your data when they fetched from DB
```

You should notice that until you don't subscribe on the chain, data doesn't go to be fetched from DB and your chain doesn't go to do anything.

Comment: Thanks!! In your example of filter(), you havent called subscribe() in the chain, then is the framework calling it? In my question, I am calling it explicitly

Comment: I think the best way to subscribe to a reactive chain can be when you want to respond to a client. Please note that you do not need to subscribe wherever you use a reactive function(Mono or Flux). You can continue the chain and prepare your response, and end the chain at the end when the response is ready, And remember that the subscription is going to end the chain and after that, you are no longer in any chain.

Comment: Ok so according to you, if I remove the subscribe() call from save() above I wont get anything in the findAll()? what if I do "reactiverepository.findAll().subscribe()" will that work?

Comment: You could something like that: 
``reactiveRepository.save(someObject).flatmap{reactiveRepository.findAll()}.subscribe()``
Please consider that if you leave `reactiveRepository.save()` alone and do not use it in any other chain which includes `subscribe()`, it not going to save anything.

Comment: I just tried removing subscribe() from save() and also didn't add it to any of the other crud methods. Still findAll() is returning the result. I think the subscribe() is getting called internally by the framework itself.